# How to get the href attribute of the ancestor <a> tag with respect to the decedent child <h3> tag using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, getattribute

I'm trying to get an `<a>` element, in case its nested (inner) `<h3>` tag contains specific text. How should I do that? Suppose that the structure is like below:

```
<a href="https://example.com">
    <section class="section">
        <div class="section-content">
            <div class="section-inner">
                <h3>
                    Are you searching for specific keyword here?
                </h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</a>
```

This HTML is a part of longer HTML text which is all inside a `<body>` tag. Meaning that the source HTML has multiples of this structure, so one can iterate over these.

The search string is "you searching", so the element should be matched. After matching the element, I want to obtain a tag's `href`'s value which is: `https://example.com`

Currently, and after playing with this, I know how to match `h3` tag by conditioning on the text inside it, but not sure how can I obtain `href`'s of parent `<a>` tag after the matching is accomplished.

```
elem = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//h3[contains(text(), 'you searching')]")
# elem is h3 tag...
```

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the value of `href` attribute of the `<a>` tag with respect to the `<h3>` tag text *Are you searching for specific keyword here?* you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *xpath* and `normalize-space()`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h3[normalize-space()='Are you searching for specific keyword here?']//ancestor::a[1]").get_attribute("href"))
  ```
- Using *xpath* and `contains()`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h3[contains(., 'Are you searching for specific keyword here?')]//ancestor::a[1]").get_attribute("href"))
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `visibility_of_element()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *xpath* and `normalize-space()`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h3[normalize-space()='Are you searching for specific keyword here?']//ancestor::a[1]"))).get_attribute("href"))
  ```
- Using *xpath* and `contains()`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h3[contains(., 'Are you searching for specific keyword here?')]//ancestor::a[1]"))).get_attribute("href"))
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```